# making an un-ordered list for (mega drop down)

Tags: html, css

Work on making an un-ordered list's with 100% of the body not the parent li which has display: inline-block (mega drop down menu).

I'm aware that `width : 100%` makes that element's width 100% of the parent. Right now I'm trying to make a mega drop down menu. I got a `ul` then an `li` then `ul` for a submenu if I put 100 % on the submenu I guess it will be 100% of the `li`(that's what I have now) . I want it to be 100% of the body or be the same size as the top `nav.ul` so Im having problem figuring out how to extend the width to be 100% of the body or the upper ul. I know I could set the submenu's width with px and put a negative margin left to position it (that seems messy). I'm wondering how you would make this mega drop down effect. the ul.submenu's li or `a` tag probably wont just be there any more I will put a div so I could put images text boxes, etc.

basically in the code below I can't put `width: 100%;` in `.container ul ul.sub` to be 100% of the body or top ul. I want to do something like that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>myDrop</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){

        })
    </script>
    <style>
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
        .container{
            background: black;
        }
        .container ul > li{
            display: inline-block;
            list-style-type: none;
            position: relative;
        }
        .nav a{
            display: block;
            padding: 0 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        .container ul ul.sub{
            position: absolute;
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
            /*background: red;*/
        }
        .container ul li:hover > ul{
            display: list-item;
            opacity: 1;
            height: 700%;
            /*top: 60px;*/
        }
        .nav li{
            position: relative;
        }
        .nav li ul{
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            background: red;
        }
        .nav li ul li{
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        .container a{
            color:white;
            text-decoration: none;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Success</a>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li><a href="#">Success Submenu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Success Submenu</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Entrepeneurship</a>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li><a href="#">Entrepeneurship submenu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Entrepeneurship submenu</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Career</a>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li><a href="#">Career Submenu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Career Submenu</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Motivation</a>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li><a href="#">Motivation Submenu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Motivation Submenu</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Videos</a>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li><a href="#">Videos Submenu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Videos Submenu</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Quotes</a>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li><a href="#">Quotes Submenu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Quotes Submenu</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
    .nav{
        position: relative;
    }
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container{
  background: black;
}
.container ul > li{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  /*position: relative;*/
}
.nav{
  position: relative;
}
.nav a{
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.container ul ul.sub{
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  /*background: red;*/
}
.container ul li:hover > ul{
  display: list-item;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 400%;
  /*top: 60px;*/
}
.nav li{
  /*position: relative;*/
}
.nav li ul{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
}
.nav li ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
}
.container a{
  color:white;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Success</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="#">Success Submenu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Success Submenu</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Entrepeneurship</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="#">Entrepeneurship submenu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Entrepeneurship submenu</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Career</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="#">Career Submenu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Career Submenu</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Motivation</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="#">Motivation Submenu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Motivation Submenu</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Videos</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="#">Videos Submenu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Videos Submenu</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Quotes</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="#">Quotes Submenu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Quotes Submenu</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```